# select all people in dbpedia associated with particular concept/occupation/profession

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to select all people in wikipedia with a particular profession, occupation or are known for a particular field (i.e. contains the string of the occupation or profession).

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor. 
}
LIMIT 100
```

Produces sort of what I want but I also want to include their Profession/Occupation (both of which are ?Profession or ?occupation) but the following doesn't return anything:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/profession> ?profession.
}
LIMIT 100
```

Or including ?Occupation doesn't work either as some don't have a profession entry but have an occupation. I just want all people (and their influenced list) for a particular profession/occupation i.e. "psychology" or "architect". I want basically a table:

```
Person | Profession/Occupation | Known For | Influenced Person | Profession/Occupation | Known For
```

The below is obviously wrong but something like this....

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
 ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/profession> ?profession. (or ?fields/?occupation)
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor.
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/profession> ?profession. (or ?fields/?occupation)
}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Please have a look at SPARQL UNION, this should work for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason*, but it seems that people in DBpedia who have `dbo:influenced` or `dbo:knownFor` don't have `dbo:profession` or `dbo:occupation`.

So, your query won't work, and you will have to find some other way to find the information you need, possibly by looking at `dbp:fields` or `rdf:type`.

---

* My *guess* is that `dbo:influenced` and `dbo:knownFor` is used for scientists and scientists don't have occupation or profession in DBpedia.

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia is extraction of wikipedia infoboxes. If you look at the result of the first query and take one example out of it, check in wikipedia, you will see that there is no **profession or occupation** is used in the infoboxes. For example, let us look at http://dbpedia.org/page/Jerry_Coyne, wikipedia page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Coyne. In wikipedia page, we can not find any information about profession or occupation in infobox. This is because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_scientist is used as template and there is no occupation/profession in that template. On the other hand there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_person template, we can find **occupation** and **known for**. Therefore, below query will work:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/occupation> ?occupation.
}
LIMIT 100
```

But this one will query only extraction of page which used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_person and will not return any page which used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_scientist.